# Copy row to same table with different ID

Tags: sql

I have table Match, with this **columns:** `ID(with Identity spec.),Team1,Team2`.
I need copy the row with `ID=1` with all columns to NEW row with new `automatic ID`.

Now I have this **code:**

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Match ON
INSERT INTO Match (ID,Team1,Team2)
SELECT
  ???,Team1,Team2
FROM
  Match
WHERE ID='1';
```

But I don't know, how do I get a new automatic ID?

Comment: `SET IDENTITY_INSERT Match ON` is specifically to turn *off* new automatic IDs *(it turns on the ability to insert them yourself, instead of the RDBMS creating them for you)*.  So, why are you using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your ID column is auto-increment then do

```
INSERT INTO Match (Team1,Team2)
SELECT
  Team1,Team2
FROM
  Match
WHERE ID='1';
```

Comment: if i try this, i have this error: Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table 'Match' either when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON or when a replication user is inserting into a NOT FOR REPLICATION identity column.

Comment: Hi @kate, do `SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFF` and try it

Answer (score 2):

By not turning on `IDENTITY_INSERT` and letting the system create the `ID`:

```
INSERT INTO Match (Team1,Team2)
SELECT
  Team1,Team2
FROM
  Match
WHERE ID=1;
```

When `IDENTITY_INSERT` is turned on, you're telling the system "I'm going to assign a value where normally you would auto-generate one", and so you would have to provide an explicit value. But since the *default* behaviour of the system is to auto-generate one, and what you *want* is the auto-generated value, you shouldn't turn this option on.

There's no facility to ask the system "please give me the next auto-generated value you *would* have assigned" (SQL Server 2012 has [Sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx)s, which are similar in concept to `IDENTITY` columns and do support the ability to ask for values, but they two systems aren't the same)

Answer (score 2):

Here is snippet.

```
INSERT INTO Match (Team1,Team2)
SELECT
  Team1,Team2
FROM
  Match
WHERE ID='1';
```

Answer (score 2):

You simply don't pass it!

```
INSERT INTO Match (Team1,Team2)
SELECT
  Team1,Team2
FROM
  Match
WHERE ID='1';
```